# Configure Parent Child Class Relationship of Same Entity in Entity Framework Core

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

I working on Entity Framework core and need to implement Parent Child relationship of same 'Question' entity into QuestionHierarchy entity. During data migration, I am getting following error. I have also got config class below

### Data Migration Error

```
Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_QuestionHierarchy_Questions_ParentQuestionId' on table 'QuestionHierarchy' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
```

Could not create constraint. See previous errors.

### Question Entity

```
public class QuestionDataModel : IDataModel<Guid>
{
    public QuestionDataModel()
    {
        ParentQuestionsInHierarchy = new HashSet<QuestionHierarchyDataModel>();
        ChildQuestionsInHierarchy = new HashSet<QuestionHierarchyDataModel>();

    }
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<QuestionHierarchyDataModel> ParentQuestionsInHierarchy { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<QuestionHierarchyDataModel> ChildQuestionsInHierarchy { get; set; }

}
```

### Question Hierarchy Table

```
public class QuestionHierarchyDataModel 
{
    public QuestionHierarchyDataModel()
    {

    }

    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid ParentQuestionId { get; set; }
    public virtual QuestionDataModel ParentQuestions{ get; set; }
    public Guid ChildQuestionId { get; set; }
    public virtual QuestionDataModel ChildQuestions { get; set; }

}
```

### Question Entity Config class

```
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<QuestionDataModel> builder)
    {

        builder.ToTable("Questions");
        builder.HasKey(question => question.Id);
        builder.HasMany(question => question.ParentQuestionsInHierarchy);
        builder.HasMany(question => question.ChildQuestionsInHierarchy);

    }
```

### Question Hierarchy Config Class

```
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<QuestionHierarchyDataModel> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("QuestionHierarchy");
        builder.HasKey(questionHierarchy => questionHierarchy.Id);

        builder
            .HasOne(questionHierarchy => questionHierarchy.ParentQuestions)
            .WithMany(question => question.ParentQuestionsInHierarchy)
            .HasForeignKey(questionHierarchy => questionHierarchy.ParentQuestionId);

        builder
           .HasOne(questionHierarchy => questionHierarchy.ChildQuestions)
           .WithMany(question => question.ChildQuestionsInHierarchy)
           .HasForeignKey(questionHierarchy => questionHierarchy.ChildQuestionId);
    }
```

Comment: You have to turn the cascade delete off for at least one of the relationships and handle deletion manually or with database trigger. There are a lot of similar questions here btw.

Comment: is it reasonable to remove navigation properties as with LINQ and join I still can get require data ??